# How to change pandas dataframe structure?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has columns : ch_name and values (separate columns) and for the index is datetime. I want to make like: ch_name must be column name and values must be in the data frame

How it is looks like now:

```
                                                               ch_name    value
time                                                                           
2019-01-22 00:00:00  Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...    0.006
2019-01-22 00:01:00  Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...    0.006
2019-01-22 00:02:00  Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...    0.006
2019-01-22 00:03:00  Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...    0.006
2019-01-22 00:04:00  Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...    0.006
...                                                                ...      ...
2019-01-22 23:56:00                             LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot  594.000
2019-01-22 23:57:00                             LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot  594.000
2019-01-22 23:58:00                             LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot  594.000
2019-01-22 23:59:00                             LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot  594.000
2019-01-22 23:59:00                             LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot  594.000

[239040 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to be look like:

```
                     Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr    LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot    ch_name 3        .... ch_name 166
time                                                                           
2019-01-22 00:00:00      0.006                                                 ....                 values
2019-01-22 00:01:00      0.006                                                 ....
2019-01-22 00:02:00      0.006                                                 ....
2019-01-22 00:03:00      0.006                                                 ....
2019-01-22 00:04:00      0.006                                                 ....
...                                                                
2019-01-22 23:56:00      ....                                                 594.000
2019-01-22 23:57:00      ....                                                 594.000
2019-01-22 23:58:00      ....                                                 594.000
2019-01-22 23:59:00      ....                                                 594.000
2019-01-22 23:59:00 (values have to be saved)                                 594.000

[239040 rows x 166 columns]
```

NOTE: There is 166 channels, but pandas only shows me 2 of them and values are full for each day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pivot_table like below

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame([[Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:00:00'), 'Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...', 0.006], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:01:00'), 'Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...', 0.006], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:02:00'), 'Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...', 0.006], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:03:00'), 'Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...', 0.006], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:04:00'), 'Housekeeping.Cardframe_+X_heater-0_Switch_Curr...', 0.006], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 23:56:00'), 'LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot', 594.0], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 23:57:00'), 'LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot', 594.0], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 23:58:00'), 'LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot', 594.0], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 23:59:00'), 'LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot', 594.0], [Timestamp('2019-01-22 23:59:00'), 'LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot', 594.0]], columns=('time', 'ch_name', 'value'))
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)

df.pivot_table(values='value', index='time', columns='ch_name')
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about having NaN values after this code? I checked before this code there is 0 NaN, but after df.pivot_table I have 56 NaN values

Comment: That is because all of your new columns don't have value for all indexes(time) so it will put Nan if value is missing  for a column and time. You need to use df.fillna method fill those with default value